# Regex from case-sensitive to non-case sensitive

Tags: java, android, xml, compiler-errors, apktool

I had an .APK file that has folders and documents with capital letters in it. Example, icon_RED.png. I change this name to icon_red.png. Now, of course, any document or different drawable (mdpi, xdpi, xxdpi, etc.) will be calling icon_RED.png, not icon_red.png. There is something I believe with the "regex" that causes it to be "case insensitive". Is there a way to make it not case sensitive? So if it is calling icon_red.png or icon_RED.png or icON_ReD.png it will direct to the same file, icon_red.png. If there is any way to do this or need any information on what I mean, please let me know. Here is the initial error that is generated from changing a file.

```
W: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\apktool\r\res\drawable-hdpi\admin_PIKEK.png: error: File is case-insensitive equivalent to: C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\apktool\r\res\drawable\admin_pikek.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename all of your `icon_RED.png` files in your `res` folder (in the different density folders) to `icon_red.png`, not just one of them.

Android resources should be all lowercase - see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0g3SUA3yoCk for a discussion on why that is.

Comment: Yes but there are over 100 files that are being called for 1 drawable, and its for tons of drawables. It would take hours to change them all. I would need to do it to every single file in the res and smali. That is why I am looking for a way to change the regex to be case insensitive. This is in Dex Smali.